# Individual SELECT statement outputs are correct, when JOINed the output is incorrect

Tags: sqlite

I have tried lowercase and UPPERCASE to fix the problem, both have failed.

I have a banking dataset from the FDIC.

When I run each SELECT statement separately I receive the correct output:

```
SELECT
AVG(PCR.lnlsdepr) as NetLoansAndLeasesToDeposits
FROM 
All_Reports_20160331_Performance_and_Condition_Ratios as 
PCR
```

Output:(77%)

```
76.6238024035116
```

The second SELECT statement run separately is also correct (e.g. It outputs the amount of money in bank accounts with less than $250,000 as $5.2 Trillion:

```
SELECT
sum(CAST(LD.IDdepsam as int)) AS 
DepositAccountsWith$LessThan$250k
FROM 
'All_Reports_20160331_Deposits_Based_on_the_
$250,000_Reporting_Threshold' as LD
```

Correct Output: ($5,216,146,035,000, $5.2 Trillion)

```
5216146035
```

However when I combine the two queries into one query, the output, of the second input, is incorrect. e.g. It outputs the total amount of money in USA bank accounts with less than $250,000 as $31 quintillion, instead of $5.2 Trillion.

```
SELECT
AVG(PCR.lnlsdepr) as NetLoansAndLeasesToDeposits,
sum(CAST(LD.IDdepsam as int)) AS 
DepositAccountsWith$LessThan$250k
FROM 
'All_Reports_20160331_Deposits_Based_on_the_$250,000_ 
 Reporting_Threshold' as LD
JOIN 
All_Reports_20160331_Performance_and_Condition_Ratios 
as PCR
```

Output: 
[image]

I tried converting everything to lowercase, but still received the incorrect output:

```
select 
avg(pcr.lnlsdepr) as 'NetLoansAndLeASesToDeposits',
sum(cast(ld.IDdepsam as int)) as 
'DepositAccountsWith$LessThan$250k'
from 
'All_Reports_20160331_Deposits_BASed_on_the_
$250,000_Reporting_Threshold' as ld
join 
'All_Reports_20160331_Performance_and_Condition_Ratios' 
as pcr
```

Output (incorrect): 
[image]

I tried UPPERCASE and still received an incorrect output: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you joining the 2 datasets? 
The results you need can be calculated separately since they are not related and presented into 1 row like this:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT AVG(lnlsdepr)
  FROM All_Reports_20160331_Performance_and_Condition_Ratios) 
  AS NetLoansAndLeasesToDeposits,
  (SELECT sum(CAST(IDdepsam as int))
  FROM 'All_Reports_20160331_Deposits_Based_on_the_$250,000_Reporting_Threshold') 
  AS DepositAccountsWith$LessThan$250k
```

This way you don't need the join overhead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have multiple rows in each table and they are multiplying.

```
SELECT x.NetLoansAndLeasesToDeposits, y."DepositAccountsWith$LessThan$250k"
FROM (SELECT AVG(PCR.lnlsdepr) as NetLoansAndLeasesToDeposits
      FROM 
All_Reports_20160331_Performance_and_Condition_Ratios as 
PCR
     ) x CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT sum(CAST(LD.IDdepsam as int)) AS 
"DepositAccountsWith$LessThan$250k"
      FROM 
"All_Reports_20160331_Deposits_Based_on_the_
$250,000_Reporting_Threshold" LD
     ) y;
```

Comment: @user2755660 . . . Is there a reason that you unaccepted this answer for an equivalent one posted 23 minutes afterwards?